# How to "turn off" Key controls for buttons in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Okay, so I'm currently working on a very simple app.
The basic idea is to use the Up/Down arrows to move the character up and Down. This worked fine, but I wanted to "play around" with it, so I ended up Changing the FormBorder to None and added a somewhat custom Border which contains three buttons.
Now whenever I press the Up/Down Arrows, I don't move the Character, but end up choosing between the buttons as if i were pressing Tab.
How do I turn the controls for the buttons off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set their `TabStop` property to false. You could also try setting `Focusable` to false.

Basically, you just want to remove them from the tab order that windows assumes so you can navigate forms without using a mouse.

Comment: This could change based on your display tech, but the idea is the same. I assumed WPF.

Comment: Yes WPF. I already did set TabStop to false on all of them and I can only find Focused, no Focusable, and when I assign this I get an error, cause the buttons are "read only". And I also tried to set all their TabIndexes to 0, but they still seem to be highlighted in the same order of which I added them.

Comment: CloseButton.Focusable doesn't exist. There is no Property named Focusable... However if you can see that property, it may be because I have 2013?? I did however see the Property: Focused, but it gives an error when I try to assign it, saying that the button is "read only" - whatever that Means..

Comment: CloseButton is not a standard WPF control. Is there a piece of information I am missing?

Comment: Oh, CloseButton is the name of one of my Buttons.

Comment: Have you tried setting the properties in XAML like my example? Button.Focusable should exist and be settable in XAML.

Comment: I see! I just didn't realize it was in XAML, however it was obvious, just me being a noob. Ok, I'll try that

Comment: Out of curiosity, what fixed it for you?

Comment: The XAML code, however I haven't learned XAML yet, so I'm not really sure if I did it right. But it did Work, so I must have done something right

Comment: XAML is a really good thing to learn if you are going to use WPF. Programmatically setting properties of controls is not generally the right answer with this technology. Glad you got it working though.

Comment: I might start to learn XAML in the near future. Thanks for your help!